# Java jSerialPort with Arduino: Outputs not printing correctly

Tags: java, c++, arduino, arduino-uno

my outputs are coming like:
[image: Output image]
When I expect the outputs to be Hello.

I suspect this to be to do with thread interference, so I changed the ComPortTimouts to SerialPort.TIMEOUT_READ_BLOCKING however I do not get any output doing this.

Here is my Java code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort;
import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPortDataListener;
import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPortEvent;

public class Arduino {
private static final SerialPort port =     SerialPort.getCommPort("/dev/cu.usbmodem1101");
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    port.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_READ_BLOCKING, 0, 0);

    if (port.openPort()) {
        System.out.println("Port opened");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error opening port: May be in use or doesn't exist");
    }

    port.addDataListener(new SerialPortDataListener() {
        @Override
        public int getListeningEvents() { 
            return SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_AVAILABLE; 
        }

        @Override
        public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
            if (event.getEventType() == SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_AVAILABLE) {
                try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(port.getInputStream())) {
                    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                        System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
                    }
                }

            } 
        }
     });

    port.addDataListener(new SerialPortDataListener() {

        @Override
        public int getListeningEvents() {
            return SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_WRITTEN;
        }

        @Override
        public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
            if(event.getEventType() == SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_WRITTEN) {
                System.out.println("Data written successfully");
            }
            
        }
        
    });
    
}
}
```

And here is my Arduino code:

```
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
    while (Serial.available() < 0) {
        return;
  }

    Serial.write("Hello");
    delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: `Serial.available()` is count of bytes available. it can't be less than zero

Answer (score 0):

With `write` the Arduino doesn't send line ending character for the `scanner.hasNextLine()`.

Use `Serial.println("Hello");`

Comment: This doesn't solve my issue, I'm pretty sure its to do with threads. I still get outputs like : H, ello, Hel, lo etc

Comment: @ninesw I would change it to `if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {` in `serialEvent`

Comment: I have done that, but its still not working. Thanks for the suggestion